# Minimize window with Docky conflicts with Unity

Tags: unity, docky, animations, minimize

I'm seeing this unwanted behaviour eversince Unity came to Ubuntu. The Unity's Launcher randomly "steals" the endpoint for the minimizing animations from Docky. In other words, when I click on an icon in Docky to minimize a window, that window minimizes to Unity instead of Docky. That happens most of the time to all of the windows, although sometimes, also randomly, it happens that the windows minimize to Docky, but very rarely.

Here's how it looks when I minimize a window:
[image]
Here's how both animations should look: 
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure of the question -- are you reporting a bug or asking for a workaround?

Comment: I'm asking whether this is considered a bug in the first place. If not, is there anything that can be done to make all the windows minimize to and maximize from the actual used dock (in my case Docky).

Comment: Still the same on 16.04 LTS with cairo-dock 3.4.1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1077201

Answer (score 3):

I tried looking up this problem in other forums but none helped. So I came up with my own alternative method.

**1) Change Unity Launcher's position to bottom**

That can be done by running the following command in terminal

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

**2) Make sure auto-hide is enabled for the unity launcher and set its sensitivity to the lowest**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OAHh.png)

**3)Press super key and add random apps to the unity launcher until it line ups with the docky placement.**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIiMp.png)

And now it should work :)

Note: If you open an app that you used as a random app in step 3, it may not minimize perfectly to docky

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same or a related problem trying to minimize windows only to docky.  I think I've found a solution. If you go to docky's settings and set the configuration to none then the window minimizing will only go to your dock. I am still playing with it to see if it will continue do this.

Comment: Set what configuration to 'None'?

Comment: @91448 The dock hiding config. @ user108829 You don't have to set it to that, you just have to change that option to something else.

Comment: were is that dock hiding config?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the animation settings in compizConfig might help.

Comment: Can you provide more information about *how* to do this?

Comment: Well i checked there is not a specific setting for changing where the window minimizes to. The fish-eye zooming effect or magic lamp, is actually a window animation that compiz handles. You could try other docks and see if they have same behavior, and if you don't already have it i would suggest installing compizConfig         
`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
and in the animations settings page you can change the minimize animation. Compiz is an advanced tool so use with care. (-:

Comment: So, does this address the problem that Томица Кораћ has asked about? That's what I'm wondering--will changing settings pertaining to these Compiz animations fix that issue?

Comment: @Aaron thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I'm not able to fix this through CCSM. In CCSM > Effects > Effect Settings > Magic Lamp, there is a setting called 'Open/Close Moving End'. I tried both enabling and disabling this, but with no visible change, even after rebooting. I've tried AWN and Plank and they don't seem to have this problem.

Comment: I think I've discovered another weird detail: windows whose icons are locked to Unity's Launcher always or almost always (not sure) minimize to Docky, as they should. But windows whose icons are not locked to Unity's Launcher, that is windows whose icons show in Unity's Launcher only when they're open, always or almost always land to Unity's Launcher. Wicked...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hackourlife.com/awn-vs-cairo-dock-vs-docky-mac-style-linux-docks-reviewed/

have you tried one of the alternatives? (ie. awn? / cairo?)

*(i used to use awn and can speak for its ease on the old 10.10 environment, but haven't attempted since the changes went in to x in 11.04< ... but i'm it's still; stable at least.)

while i know this isn't a direct fix to your problems, it may be a good temporary alternative. :D

Comment: thanks @knope for your suggestion. Yes, I've tried many docks. I've been using AWN for years and still think it's probably the best one. I don't quite like Cairo just because it's got way too many nuts and bolts to tweak before you set it right for yourself. However, I switched to Docky because it's so light-weight, and yet it has almost everything I need from a dock. Also, I don't think any other dock has its fish-eye zooming effect. Many have something similar, but it's just not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best thing you can do is to disable the Unity plugin using CCSM. This will remove the Unity launcher, but the upper panel would disappear too. Then, install gnome-panel:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

And add it to start-up applications. Log out andd then log back in.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: SalsaRui thanks, but I don't want to disable the entire Unity. I like the way Unity develops, for now the only unreasonable thing about Unity is the terrible Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed (in case someone is still wondering), when the app you are minimizing is already docked to unity launcher it no longer minimizes to the launcher but instead to the dock, so to fix it I docked every single program i ever opened to launcher to avoid it being minimized to the wrong place. Seems to stop working when you move the window of the application you launched, unity seems to take over control of the app again and minimizes to the wrong place again, so unless someone knows how to fix that then this only works partially, sorry